# Java InputStream path works in main, but not in class definition?

Tags: java, maven, path, inputstream

So I am using Maven dependencies, and there is a csv file that I need to refer to in one of the jars. When I set the path with a function in main eg:

```
InputStream is = main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/folder1/folder2/file.csv");
```

I can read from the file and output it fine, but when I pass this path to a function from main eg:

```
listOfEmployees = Employee.createListOfEmployees("com/folder1/folder1/file.csv");
```

and in my Employee Class I have:

```
public static HashMap<int,Employee> createList(String Path){
//SomeStuffHere
InputStream inStream = Employee.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
//SomeStuffHere to create HashMap of Employees
return listOfEmployees;
```

What could be the problem? Main and Employee reside in the same location, so I would think the paths to that file should work with both Class files. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In one you have `main.class`, in the other you have `Employee.class.getClass()`. Spot the difference.

Comment: I am seeing `Employee.createListOfEmlpoyees(...)` but the method you showed is `createList(...)`

Comment: At least, there's a typo in your second path (`folder1\folder1`) instead of  (`folder1\folder2`), but maybe this is not the case in your original code (or should the paths be equal)?

Comment: That is a typo, the original code has the same exact file paths.

Comment: Okay but what about the method names?

Comment: Oh you were correct @immibis that extra part in the Employee version was not needed. Thanks!

Comment: @chancea yes that was a typo also. The original version calls the correct method.